# django user model - override labels in model form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to override the field labels of django's user model

i did:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["first_name", "last_name","username", "email", "password"]
    labels = {
        'first_name': 'Vorname',
        'last_name': 'Nachname',
    }
```

and in template

```
{{uform}}
```

i am getting still `First Name`, `Last Name` instead of `Vorname` and `Nachname`. am I missing something?

Comment: what django version are you using?

Comment: i am using  django 1.4

Comment: this feature enabled in django >= 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it only works with Django 1.6 or newer.

With older Django installations you will have to do it this way:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Vorname')
    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "username", "email", "password"]
```

Comment: Danke :)) didnot know that. Great!